# silence -Wparentheses-equality error

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction

Im building som software using boost 1.48 on osx 10.8 with gcc version 4.2.1 and i have started getting `-Wparentheses-equality` warnings for some of the boost source.

```
  equality comparison with extraneous parentheses
  [-Werror,-Wparentheses-equality]
        else if((state->type == syntax_element_long_set_rep))
```

I would change the code but i dont want to tinker with the library, how would i silence the warning and make the compiler continue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC):

> Most of these have both positive and negative forms; the negative form of `-ffoo` would be `-fno-foo`.

Try `-Wno-parentheses-equality`.

Comment: im quite new to this, do you mean i should add -Wno-parentheses-equality as an argument to the make command? i tried that and i still get the error

Comment: @jonathantopf No, this is an option for the compiler. If you are using Make then usually this is stored in a variable like e.g. `CXXFLAGS`. Try to look for `-Wall` (a common option that would be stored there, too) and add this option next to it.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to simply disabling the warning you can also specify certain paths to count as 'system' paths. Warnings are suppressed for system headers, so you can declare that a particular library's headers are 'system' headers and that you don't care about warnings in them.

clang's argument for this is `--system-header-prefix=<prefix>`

So for example you might say `"--system-header-prefix=boost/"`

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers

And judging by the error message you are actually using clang and not gcc.